# onchange radio button to empty value of the input field which belongs to that, in jquery

Tags: jquery

[image]

**How to make multiselect dropdown value empty when i click resource radio button?**

Here i have two radio button with some function like `hide` and `show` , at first I click resource am type something in that text field , after that am clicking project radio button i want to clear the value of the resource and its relavant field , and vise versa.

Comment: What's going on in the first section of your question? The part before the image seems like you've copy/pasted the help instructions on the question page...?

Comment: He has maybe copied it in order to get the correct syntax to paste an actual piece of code. I hope. ( Because we do like code ! :) )

Comment: I edit your post but please add your code (html + jQuery) to see what you get and what you tried, create a snippet if possible so people can help you !

Answer (score 0):

You must check if resource radio button is selected like this

```
if($("[id^=theIdButton]:checked").length == 0)){
```

}

And then try this inside if statement

```
$(".classOfYourButton select").attr("disabled",true);
```

to make the dropdown readonly